# JQuery slideToggle() vs CSS animations

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please do not flag this as a duplicate, I'm not asking about what is better to use. [I made a slideout navbar the other day](http://jsfiddle.net/w67Pj/), and I used the jQuery `slideToggle()` to get the animation working. I tried using CSS transitions, but I failed miserably. The question is, is it possible to get that effect with transitions (exactly the effect on the JSfiddle) without jQuery (or any JS at all, for that matter)? If so, how?

Comment: yes, check this http://www.identifydesign.net/tutorials/css/pure-css-animated-dropdown-menu/

Comment: Keep in mind that not all browsers support CSS3 animations. I am not sure whether JS enjoys a wider support than CSS3, but it might be something worth looking into.

Comment: As far as I've heard, most browsers do support most JS and jQuery elements (apart from IE6, but does anyone actually use that anymore?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possibile (here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DvVLw/3/) e.g. if your items height are set initially to `0` and you specify, for every submenu, an exact height to reach at the end of the animation, since CSS3 animations cannot (yet) work with `auto` keyword (so an animation from `0` to `auto` is not possible).

The height of course is hard to tell when your menu is dynamic and you don't previously know how many items it will contain

Comment: Looks like you overlooked the same thing I did. When you try to select a menu item, the menu begins to roll up again.

Comment: just a matter of css rules: see http://jsfiddle.net/DvVLw/5/ - anyway unless you adopt some tricky solution (like hiding the menu outside the visible area) possible in specific circumstances only, your problem is to specify a fixed value for height property: in my example I set arbitrarily 200px

Answer (score 2):

Sure is, but using this method you will have to play around with the `top` position initially (it is negative)

**Important parts**

```
#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -1px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    top: -245px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    display:block;
    top: 45px;
    z-index:-999; /* This is to make the menu be behind the nav bar*/
}

#nav li ul:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w67Pj/4/)

Also check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R8zca/4/) out for a simplified version of the slide effect.

Comment: Is there a CSS way to make it slide back out, instead of disappearing (it's not necessary, this is just food for thought)?

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer with that. I moved the transition code from the `:hover` to just `#nav li ul` so it'll happen on hover and when you move your mouse out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `height` `0` and `auto` why not to use CSS `transform:translateY()` with `transition: transform` ?

Is there any disadvantages of using that solution?